# StorageReference updateMetadata overwrites all properties

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I got a problem with Firebase Storage, updateMetadata() function. I want to add custom Metadata, but updateMetadata overwrites all properties. I use Firebase Storage on Flutter. Here is the code:

`StorageReference storageReference = _firebaseStorage.ref().child('filename');
storageReference.updateMetadata(StorageMetadata(customMetadata: {'receiver': 'ID'}));`

I just want to add the receiver with the given ID, but every other property like content-type is being overwritten. Is this a common issue or is there a different way to solve this problem?

Regards, Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata#update_file_metadata) says:

> You can update file metadata at any time after the file upload completes by using the updateMetadata() method. Refer to the full list for more information on what properties can be updated. **Only the properties specified in the metadata are updated, all others are left unmodified.**

So what you're seeing is not the expected behavior as far as I can tell. I can reproduce it, filed a [bug report](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2307) on the FlutterFire repo.

Until that bug is fixed, if you want to modify the metadata, you can work around the bug with these steps:

1. Read the existing metadata
2. Make the change to the values you read
3. Write the updated, complete metadata back